# Advise correct way to reference existing resource through resourceId() function

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to automate creation of load balancing rules through ARM template. But I am getting below error when I am trying to run my ARM template through Azure DevOps Pipeline.

**This line in the template**

```
"id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIPConfigurations', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'fe-acr-dev-f5-shd-000')]"
```

**giving this error**

> [error]InvalidResourceReference: Resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-acr-dev-f5-shd-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/lbi-acr-dev-f5-shd-001/frontendIPConfigurations/fe-acr-dev-f5-shd-000 referenced by resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-acr-dev-f5-shd-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/lbi-acr-dev-f5-shd-001/loadBalancingRules/rule-acr-dev-f5-shd-000 was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region. []

**Below is the full template**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name": {
            "defaultValue": "lbi-acr-dev-f5-shd-001",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
            "apiVersion": "2023-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')]",
            "location": "centralus",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard",
                "tier": "Regional"
            },
            "properties": {
                "loadBalancingRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "rule-acr-dev-f5-shd-000",
                        "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')), '/loadBalancingRules/rule-acr-dev-f5-shd-000')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIPConfigurations', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'fe-acr-dev-f5-shd-000')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": 443,
                            "backendPort": 8000,
                            "enableFloatingIP": false,
                            "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "enableTcpReset": false,
                            "loadDistribution": "Default",
                            "disableOutboundSnat": true,
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'lbi-acr-dev-f5-shd-dev443-001')]"
                            },
                            "backendAddressPools": [
                                {
                                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'lbi-acr-dev-f5-shd-dev443-001')]"
                                }
                            ],
                            "probe": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')), concat('/probes/', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')))]"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "rule-acr-dev-f5-shd-001",
                        "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')), '/loadBalancingRules/rule-acr-dev-f5-shd-001')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIPConfigurations', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'fe-acr-dev-f5-shd-001')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": 443,
                            "backendPort": 8001,
                            "enableFloatingIP": false,
                            "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "enableTcpReset": false,
                            "loadDistribution": "Default",
                            "disableOutboundSnat": true,
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'lbi-acr-dev-f5-shd-dev443-001')]"
                            },
                            "backendAddressPools": [
                                {
                                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'lbi-acr-dev-f5-shd-dev443-001')]"
                                }
                            ],
                            "probe": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')), concat('/probes/', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "probes": [
                    {
                        "name": "[parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')]",
                        "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')), concat('/probes/', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')))]",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "port": 10888,
                            "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                            "numberOfProbes": 1,
                            "probeThreshold": 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Above template is to create Load Balancing Rules only. Frontend IP Configurations, Backend Address Pools and Probe mentioned in the above template, are already exits.

I have followed documentation to call resourceId() function. `[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIPConfiguration', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'fe-acr-dev-f5-shd-000')]`

Still, it produces an error message "reference resource was not found".

So, what is the correct way to reference existing Frontend IP Configuration rule through resourceId() function?

Answer (score 0):

To reference an existing resource in arm template, the way you are proving the values is good to me. But instead of passing it directly, use a `variables` block to store the existing resource id and then pass it under the front Ip configuration block as given below.

Reference [blog](https://faultbucket.ca/2018/03/arm-template-reference-existing-resources/) by @[Jeff Miles](https://faultbucket.ca/author/jwmiles/).

```bash
"variables":{
"frontend":  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIPConfigurations', 'newlb' , 'myfip')]"
}
```

`main.json`:

```bash
"properties": {
      "frontendIPConfiguration": {
       "id": "[variables('frontend')]}",
          "frontendPort": 443,
           "backendPort": 8000,
           "enableFloatingIP": false,
           "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
            "protocol": "Tcp",
            "enableTcpReset": false,
             "loadDistribution": "Default",
             "disableOutboundSnat": true,
             "backendAddressPool": {
             "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'lbi-acr-dev-f5-shd-dev443-001')]"
                            },
             "backendAddressPools": [
                {
                   "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name'), 'lbi-acr-dev-f5-shd-dev443-001')]"
                 }
             ],
                 "probe": {
                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')), concat('/probes/', parameters('loadBalancers_lbi_acr_dev_f5_shd_001_name')))]"
               }
           }
  }
```

Alternatively, you can also use [reference()](https://ochzhen.com/blog/reference-function-arm-template) function in Arm template to reference the resource which is existed in the same template.

Comment: Thank you for you response @Jahnavi. I am now getting below error after doing modification you suggested in the ARM template. "[error]The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'variables' on object of type 'TemplateResource'. Path 'properties.template.resources[0].variables', line 1, position 490."

Comment: Have you added the variables block at the top of code? @BrijeshPatel

Comment: I have added it under resources block. Should it go above resources block? @Jahnavi

Comment: Can you try adding it on the top of the code. @BrijeshPatel